# Series And Sequences Question

Tags: sequences-and-series

Can someone help show me what I did wrong?
The question is "Find the sum of the first ten terms in this geometric series: $-5, 10, -20, \ldots$

I plugged it into this equation: $S_n = a(r^n -1)/(r-1)$ so it became $S_{10} = -5((-2)^{10} - 1))/(-2-1)$ and my answer was $-1708$, which I am certain is not the right answer.

Comment: Are you sure you evaluated that equation correctly?

I think $-5 \cdot \frac{(-2)^{10} -1}{-2-1} \neq -1708$.

Comment: That is what I got. Maybe my calculator is broken? What answer did you get?

Comment: There should be parentheses around the $(-2)$, so it is $(-2)^{10}$, not - (2^10)$.

Comment: Ah, I see. Thank you:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be

$$S_{10}=\frac{(-5)\cdot[(-2)^{10}-1]}{-2-1}=1705$$

You forgot to add a bracket for $-2$.

Comment: Thank you so much :) This answer really helped. Thank you for correcting my careless mistake

Answer (score 0):

If you are not certain if an answer is right or not, try to prove or dis-prove it!

$\begin{cases}S_{10}=-5+10+\cdots+2560\\
(-2)S_{10}=10-20+\cdots-5120\end{cases}$

So

$3\times S_{10}=-5+5120=5115=3\times1705$

and the answer is ...?

Hope this helps.